# What is the purpose of mime.cache files?

Tags: arch-linux, mime-types

What is the purpose of the `mime.cache` files on an Arch Linux KDE desktop system?

The Arch Wiki discusses `mimeapps.list` files, but does not mention `mime.cache`.

On my system, there is only one `mimeapps.list` file, but multiple `mime.cache` files. Examples:

```
/usr/share/mime/mime.cache
~/.local/share/mime/mime.cache
```

Does the local user version replace or extend the system-wide `mime.cache` file?

Can these `mime.cache` files be deleted manually (e.g., with `rm`)?

When trying to solve mime-type issues, I think it might help to remove them to avoid confusion from old cached values when I make changes.

If they are deleted, do they need to be manually recreated? If so, how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What is the purpose of the mime.cache files on an Arch Linux KDE desktop system?

`mime.cache` contains the same information as the globs2, magic, subclasses, aliases, icons, generic-icons and XMLnamespaces files, in a binary, mmappable format

> Does the local user version replace or extend the system-wide
> `mime.cache` file?

No, In GNU/Linux the system-wide configurations affect all users, whereas the user configuration affects only the current user. So, you can do any change in either of them depending on your purpose. My recommendation is never to change system-wide settings unless you know what you are doing. e.g `mime.cache` file is automatically built and so should not be customised as your precious customisations will get lost when the file is rebuilt

> Can these `mime.cache` files be deleted manually (e.g., with rm)?

Yes.

> If they are deleted, do they need to be manually recreated? If so,
> how?

```bsh
update-mime-database ~/.local/share/mime # personal
update-mime-database /usr/share/mime     # system-wide
```